# Is the mail_logger module safe for production?

Tags: emails

I'm having intermittent problems with emails that are silently failing on a production environment. I'm troubleshooting with the `mail_logger` module, and it would be extremely helpful on production.

However, for some reason I feel that this is a 'development/debugging' module and not something recommended for production. Are my fears unfounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't enable any developer backdoor features (e.g. arbitrary PHP execution, code/stack dumps, etc.) if that's your concern.

For the most part, its code base is Views integration & an admin interface wrapped around its core function; intercepting outgoing mail through [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) and storing in the `mail_logger` table.

I'd say the only concern there is privacy for your users.